# RabbitMQ java client memory leak

Tags: java, memory-leaks, rabbitmq

I'm using amqp-client-3.2.2.jar, and jdk 32 bit.

I have a java message producer running in an application, and a java message consumer running in a different application.  Both are running on my laptop each from its own executable jar file.

I am viewing the memory allocation from the task manager for both of these applications.

The memory allocation is increasing rapidly in both applications.

I have simplified the consumer code (as follows) just to investigate and hopefully fix this leak:

```
Connection _connection = null;
Channel _channel = null;
QueueingConsumer _consumer = null;
boolean _stop = false;

try {
    ConnectionFactory _factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    _factory.setHost("localhost");
    _factory.setRequestedHeartbeat(5);
    _connection = _factory.newConnection();
    _channel = _connection.createChannel();
    _channel.exchangeDeclare("keyboard_exchange", "fanout", false, true, null);
    _channel.exchangeDeclare("java_keyboard_exchange", "topic", false, true, null);
    _channel.exchangeBind("java_keyboard_exchange", "keyboard_exchange", "#");
    _channel.queueDeclare("java_keyboard_queue", false, false, false, null);
    _channel.queueBind("java_keyboard_queue", "java_keyboard_exchange", "#");
    _consumer = new QueueingConsumer(_channel);
    _channel.basicConsume("java_keyboard_queue", false, _consumer);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println("Exception occurred while creating objects: " + ex);
    _stop = true;
}

QueueingConsumer.Delivery delivery = null;

while (_stop == false) {
    try {
        delivery = _consumer.nextDelivery();
        byte[] msg = delivery.getBody();
        System.out.println(" Received: bytes=" + msg.length + " msg=" + msg);
        _consumer.getChannel().basicAck(delivery.getEnvelope().getDeliveryTag(), false);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        _stop = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more? It would be good to know what kind of data you are generating and sending. Also, `QueueingConsumer` is deprecated: http://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-java-client/v3.2.2/rabbitmq-java-client-javadoc-3.2.2/com/rabbitmq/client/QueueingConsumer.html

Comment: Thank you for telling me that QueueingConsumer has been deprecated.  I'm going to rewrite the code by implementing DefaultConsumer.  As far as the data, the consumer is reading BSON serialized data.  The serialized data is an object that contains 3 primitive arrays: byte[], long[] and int[].  The 3 arrays are always the same size as each other, but that size can vary.  For testing, I made the array size = 10.